Building local docker images tagged with current git branch name
I have a docker compose definition files with multiple services defined in it. For every service the general pattern (irrelevant lines omitted) is:
  isagog-kg2:
    build:
      context: /home/mema/code/kg2/isagog-ai-kg2
    image: isagog-kg2:1.3.3

  service-2:
    build:
      context: /home/mema/code/service2
    image: service2:dev-0.3.5

and as you can see I am tagging the images with a version string MANUALLY.
I would like to make this more robust by using the output of the following command:
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

which for example would return something like:
mema@newisa:~/code/kg2/isagog-ai-kg$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
dev-1.3.3

and using this string to tag the isagog-kg2 image with said string (isagog-kg2:dev-1.3.3)
Of course said got command needs to be run in the directory described by the docker compose context directive.
Ideally I would like all of this triggered by the simple docker compose build service2 command.
Thanks for any guidance on how to achieve this.
PS As someone did not understand my question (sorry English not my primary language) I will try to restate it:
Is there a way to use the docker compose build command in such a way that it will use the git commend (or any other means) to retrieve the current branch name in the context of the directory declared in that service and use that as a tag for the docker image?

What is your actual question?

I thought the title and description stated my goal but I'll try to make it clearer. Is there a way to use the docker compose build command in such a way that it will use the git commend (or any other means) to retrieve the current branch name in the context of the directory declared in that service and use that as a tag for the docker image?

@tripleee The OP wants dynamic image: isagog-kg2:$(cd ~/code/kg2/isagog-ai-kg && git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

@tphd thanks you for putting it more succintly :) That is what I'd like to achieve but in my ignorance I think the image tag only accepts static values or am I wrong?

@RobertAlexander I'm not tripleee, it was @-mention. :-) I am not proficient with Docker, I don't know much about compose.yaml; will try to lookup in the docs…

To better clarify I do I could use the value of a $BRANCHVERSION environment variable as the tag, but the how could the docker build command trigger the proper git command in the directory specified in the context directive?
